# Show Value when a variable is entered

Tags: javascript, authentication

im trying to show a value (Staff name) when a variable is entered under the Staff ID

this is a local hta upload into our server

im still learning hope that anyone can help me

here's the script

```
<title>Test Login</title>
<head>

 <HTA:APPLICATION 
 ID="TestLogin"
 APPLICATIONNAME="Login"
 SysMenu="no"
 BORDER="thin"
 CONTEXTMENU="no"
 ICON="images/help.ico" 
 MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
 MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
 window.resizeTo 400,250
 RESIZE="no"
 SCROLL="no"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 WINDOWSTATE="normal" />

</head>

<body STYLE="font:14 pt arial; color:white;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
(GradientType=1, StartColorStr='#000000', EndColorStr='#0000FF')">

<script type = "text/javascript">

var count = 2;
function validate() {
var un = document.myform.username.value;
var pw = document.myform.pword.value;

var valid = false;
```

`var unArray = ["4020004", "4020031", "4020025",];`

`var pwArray = ["4020004", "4020031", "4020025",];`

```
for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
valid = true;
break;
}
}

if (valid) {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("CALL MAIN WINDOW", 1, false);
return false;
}

var t = " tries";
if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

if (count >= 1) {
alert ("Invalid username and/or password.  You have " + count + t + " left.");
document.myform.username.value = "";
document.myform.pword.value = "";
setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
count --;
}

else {
alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
document.myform.pword.value = "";
document.myform.username.disabled = true;
document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
return false;
}

}

</script>

 <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
 </script>

<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="#" alt="#" align="middle" width="200" height="200">
<p>
<p>TEST LOGIN</p>
<form name = "myform">
<p>Staff ID <input type="text" name="username"> </p>
**TRYING TO SHOW STAFF NAME HERE WHEN ID IS ENTER**
<p>Password <input type="password" name="pword"></p>
</form>
```

This is the original script http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/loginpass2.shtml

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an external script, i can't really find where you store the ID.
add the following somewhere in your code where you want to show the staff name:

```
<div class="staff-name-placeholder">Enter ID</div>
```

modify input:

```
<p>Staff ID <input type="text" name="username"> </p>
```

To:

```
<p>Staff ID <input type="text" name="username" onchange="updatestaff();"> </p>
```

add following on the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatestaff()
{
    document.getElementById('staff-name-placeholder').innerHTML='[PLACE ID]';
}
</script>
```

It does the following:

- binds a listener when the input 'username' is changed.
- searches the element with id 'staff-name-placeholder'
- replaces the HTML inside the element with '[PLACE ID]'.

Of course, the real id isn't given yet, you must pass it through your other script.

I hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: the id is in the script,see var unArray/pwArray